# Top 10 Bike Stations by User

Tags: python, filter, group-by, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to filter a bike company's 10 Top stations along with the user type.

I tried groupby but do not know how to filter.

`df(df['start_station_name']).head(10)`

> TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in ()
> ----> 1 df(df['start_station_name']).head(10)
>
> TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

I expected to see a breakdown by the highest of stations along with the number of subscribers using that station.

Comment: You used parenthesis instead of brackets: `df[df['start_station_name']].head(10)`

Comment: You're passing `df['start_station_name']` into `df()`, trying to use `df` as a function. The error message is telling you that you cannot call `df` as a function. ALso note that `.head` will get you the first 10 rows from that data frame, but unless they are ordered, they may not be the 10 rows you're after and you'd need to sort and / or group the data first.

Comment: Thank you.  I've noticed using head doesn't automatically give me the highest trafficed stations.  I will sort first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean?:

```
df['start_station_name'].head(10)
```

If not you probably meant:

```
df.head(10)
```

Or:

```
df[df['start_station_name'] == your_value].head(10)
```

Otherwise it's unclear.

A `DataFrame` object is **not** callable, only subscriptable, so only allowed to be used with `[` `]`, so probably the above should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much.  The second part groupby user type to determine how many subcribers are at each location is pretty tough to figure out.

Comment: @RickJ You can ask another question, please up-vote too

Comment: @RickJ Just click on the up arrow on my post to up-vote

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response.  Game changer.